# Как удалить повторяющиеся подряд символы из памяти? Язык С

Tags: c, строки, удаление

Допустим, есть строка aaabcde, а нужно чтобы было abcde. Я реализовала код, который работает, но есть ли какие-нибудь функции или библиотеки, которые помогут именно **удалить** из строки символ? Ни циклом, ни принтами, ни созданием нового массива, а именно был массив char stroka[7] = "aaabcde", а стала char stroka[5] = "abcde"? Буду благодарна, если подскажите или намекнете, где можно почитать об этом. Находила информацию об этом, точнее реализацию на языке с++, но на **с** не смогла найти, возможно, плохо искала(

*P.S. не ругайтесь, пожалуйста, если я путаю термины "массив" и "строка", я новичок.*

Comment: Эм, это делается циклом и двумя указателями за один проход.

Comment: Если имеется объект с типом `char [7]`, то никаким манипуляциями, ни в С, ни в С++, превратить его в объект с типом `char [5]` не получится.

Comment: Не относится к вопросу, но сделайте обе строки на символ длиннее. В C строки завершаются нулевым символом. Он не виден в литералах, но он есть.

Comment: @user7860670, *`"never say, never again..."`*. По крайней мере GNU-сный Си вполне себе ест вот такую конструкцию --   `for (int i = 7; i > 3; i -= 2) {     char a[i];    strncpy(a, "123456789", i);  a[i] = 0; printf("sizeof(a) = %d  a = <%s>\n",  (int)sizeof(a), a);  }` (и говорит, что sizeof(a) меняется)

Comment: @avp, вы хотите сказать что создаются VLA массивы разной длины? Но вопрос был про изменение типа переменной.

Comment: Да, немного путаете... Длина ***строки*** в С определяется не размером массива, а количеством ненулевых элементов в нем  до первого нулевого элемента.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, да, при каждой инициализации блока создается новый VLA массив, но формально это та же самая переменная (в смысле, обозначаемая тем же именем в программе)

Comment: @avp, с тем же успехом можно, написав `{char a[7];}{char a[5];}`, утверждать, что мы успешно сменили тип массива `a` с `char [7]` на `char [5]`.

Comment: @wololo, надеюсь не стоит объяснять разницу между одинаковыми именами в одном и **разных** блоках?

Comment: @avp, В вашем примере `for (...) {char a[i]; ...}` в конце каждой итерации цикла время жизни объекта `a` подходит к концу. А на следующей итерации цикла начинается время жизни _другого_ объекта. Концептуально, никакого отношения к предыдущему объекту он не имеет. Так что разницы между одним и разными блоками в данном конкретном случае никакой.

Comment: @wololo, ну, наконец-то речь пошла о разных **активациях блоков**. С этой точки зрения, естественно, объекты разные. Но с т.з. логики кода блока (я имею в виду *естественную для программиста* логику) это та же самая переменная, независимо от конкретной активации

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Полагаю, что требование изменения типа переменной - это всё-таки отсебятина, а требовалось сжать строку на месте. Для этого можно пройти по строке циклом, на каждом шаге проверяя, не совпадает ли текущий символ с начальным символом последовательности. Если нет - то сдвинуть индекс начала и переписать символ на его окончательное место. В конце работы записать нулевой символ после оставшихся, чтобы строковые функции C корректно обрабатывали измененную строку.

```
char s[100] = "aabcccdeeefgggg";
if(s) {
   int left = 0;
   int right = 1;
   while (s[right]) {
       if (s[right] != s[left])
           s[++left] = s[right];
       right++;    
   }
   s[left+1] = '\0';
   printf("%s", s);
}


>>  abcdefg
```